# Decoding String (from header) encoded by Base64 and RFC2047 in Java

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, base64, decoding

I'm working on a function to decode a string (from a header) that is encoded in both Base64 and RFC2047 in Java.

Given this header:

> SGVhZGVyOiBoZWFkZXJ2YWx1ZQ0KQmFkOiBOYW1lOiBiYWRuYW1ldmFsdWUNClVuaWNvZGU6ID0/VVRGLTg/Qj81YmV4NXF5eTU2dUw2SUNNNTZ1TDVMcTY3N3lNNWJleDVxeXk2WUdVNklDTTZZR1U/PSA9P1VURi04P0I/NUxxNjc3eU01YmV4NW9tQTVMaU41cXl5Nzd5TTVZdS81cGE5NXBhODVMcTY0NENDPz0NCg0K

My expected output is:

> Header: headervalue Bad: Name: badnamevalue Unicode:
> 己欲立而立人，己欲達而達人，己所不欲，勿施於人。

The only relevant function that I have found and tried was `Base64.decodeBase64(headers)`, which produces this when printed out:

> Header: headervalue Bad: Name: badnamevalue Unicode:
> =?UTF-8?B?5bex5qyy56uL6ICM56uL5Lq677yM5bex5qyy6YGU6ICM6YGU?= =?UTF-8?B?5Lq677yM5bex5omA5LiN5qyy77yM5Yu/5pa95pa85Lq644CC?=

To solve this, I've been trying MimeUtility.decode() by converting the byte array returned from `Base64.decodeBase64(headers)` to InputStream, but the result was identical as above.

```
InputStream headerStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decodeBase64(headers));
InputStream result = MimeUtility.decode(headerStream, "quoted-printable");
```

Have been searching around the internet but have yet found a solution, wondering if anyone knows ways to decode MIME headers from resulted byte arrays?

Any help is appreciated! It's also my first stack overflow post, apologies if I'm missing anything but please let me know if there's more information that I can provide!

Comment: How are you converting this `InputStream` to the string you've shown us?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I'm working with the InternetHeaders class, so the output (after the code I typed in in the post) was actually `return new InternetHeaders(result)`.  I had a function that takes in InternetHeaders and did `Enumeration<String> enumA = a.getAllHeaderLines()` and then got that string output by looping through enumA and `System.out.println enumA.nextElement()`

Comment: From reading the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html), I *think* the [`decodeText(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html#decodeText(java.lang.String)) method is what you want, or possibly [`decodeWord(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html#decodeWord(java.lang.String)).

Comment: For people reading the post in the future: it was indeed decodeText()!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base64 you have there **actually is** what you pasted. Including the bizarre =?UTF-8?B? weirdness.

The stuff that follows is *again* base64.

There's base64-encoded data inside your base-64 encoded data. As Xzibit would say: I put some Base64 in your base64 so you can base64 while you base64. Why do I feel old all of a sudden?

In other words, the base64 input you get is a crazy, extremely inefficient format invented by a crazy person.

My advice is that you tell them to come up with something less insane.

Failing that:

Search the resulting string for the regex pattern and then again apply base64 decode to the stuff in the middle.

Also, you're using some third party base64 decoder, probably apache. Apache libraries tend to suck. Base64 is baked into java, there is no reason to use worse libraries here. I've fixed that; the Base64 in this snippet is `java.util.Base64`. Its API is slightly different.

```java
String sourceB64 = "SGV..."; // that input base64 you have.
byte[] sourceBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(sourceB64);
String source = new String(sourceBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("=\\?UTF-8\\?B\\?(.*?)\\?=");
Matcher m = p.matcher(source);
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
int curPos = 0;
while (m.find()) {
  out.append(source.substring(curPos, m.start()));
  curPos = m.end();
  String content = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(m.group(1)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  out.append(content);
}
out.append(source.substring(curPos));

System.out.println(out.toString());
```

If I run that, I get:

```
Header: headervalue
Bad: Name: badnamevalue
Unicode: 己欲立而立人，己欲達而達 人，己所不欲，勿施於人。
```

Which looks exactly like what you want.

Explanation of that code:

- It first base64-decodes the input, and turns that into a string. (Your idea of using InputStream is a red herring. That doesn't help at all here. You just want to turn bytes into a string, you do it as per line 3 of that snippet. Pass the byte array and the encoding those bytes are in, that's all you need to do).
- It then goes on the hunt for `=?UTF-8?B?--base64here--?=` inside your base64. The base64-in-the-base64.
- It then decoder *that* base64, turns it into a string in the same fashion, and replaces it.
- It just adds everything besides those `=?UTF-8?B?...?=` segments verbatim.

Comment: The "bizarre weirdness" is RFC 2047 quoted-printable which the MimeUtility class claims to be able to decode, although I have not used it.

Comment: @DavidConrad @rzwitserloot thanks to both of your help! I was too caught into all the new concepts and this did help clear it up. But yeah to decode it successfully it was indeed to `Base64decode` then decode the RFC2047 with `decodeText()`